# Prompt box not showing

Tags: javascript, html

Hi stack flow community,

I've made a simple odd/even number check which when run doesn't display the initial prompt box. Pretty sure it's to do with the function but can't for the life of me find out why. Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head> </head>

<body>

    <h1> Javascript Practice </h1>

    <script>

        function oddOrEven(number){

            var result = number%2;

            if(result === 0){
            alert("The number you have chosen is even");
            }else{
            alert("the number you have chosen is odd");
            }

            return();

        }


        var x = prompt("Enter a number:");

        alert("You have chosen: " +x );

        oddOrEven(x);        



    </script>

</body>
```

New to javascript so forgive me on how simple this fix may be.

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. Look at the error message that is displayed there.

Comment: Alternatively, paste the code into http://jshint.com/

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."

Comment: Go to the browser console and see if there are any errors

Comment: return() should be return

Comment: I've used jSHint which has reported there is nothing wrong with my javascript? Could it be my HTML?

Comment: Both the alert and prompt wont display?

Comment: I managed to get it working now - thanks Jeremy - it's return not return()  thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing *return()* with *return* in OddOrEven did the trick.

I used jslint.com and its first complaint was:

```
Don't wrap assignment statements in parens.
            return();
```

So I redid without the parentheses, reran the javascript code at http://javascript.cs.lmu.edu/runner/
and it worked.

Comment: Thanks again Jeremy